Swear in vs sworn in
Someone elected to office is sworn in and  the event is called a swearing-in ceremony.
Mr X has been elected chief minister. I saw a public announcement in a newspaper  saying Mr X 'will swear in as Chief Minister'.
Is this correct usage?

Typically, the phrasal verb swear in is not used intransitively. As an example, U.S. presidents are generally sworn in by the chief justice of the U.S. Supreme Court. It is not idiomatic to say, for instance, that Joe Biden *”swore in.”

Where was the announcement? Do you have a link? Google turns up a number of results for this usage, but almost all are from sources in India; it might be a feature of Indian English not found in other dialects.

Yes, it is an announcement published in newspapers announcing the swearing in of the newly elected chief minister of a state in India. I think it is just wrong idiomatic usage arising from translation from a vernacular to English. Incidentally, it says 'Heartfelt Welcome to everyone', which also sounds wrong.

Re "wrong idiom", Indian English uses different idioms.

I've checked in the usual respected dictionaries, and none gives the intransitive usage. But examples can be found: 'He swore in as Minister for the Ecological Transition of Italy on February 13, 2021.' [OECD]
